What would caused the chained Queueable inside the batch to run recursively?
I have a batch that is scheduled to run daily.
This batch can delete and update the records.
this is the sample of my batch:
public class BatchTest implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable, Database.stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts {


public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        BatchTest btch= new BatchTest();
        Database.executeBatch(btch, 50);        
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    // query the case records
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Case> casesList){
    // deletes the childs of the case. send emails inside the trigger of the after delete 
   //case..

    // deletes the child.. no logic inside delete child trigger of the child record

   // soql of the child record
   // update the child record
   // another update of the child record for different field

    // Queueable called, passing the parent and child records
    System.enqueueJob(new Que1(Case CaseREcord, Child__c childRecords));

   // send an email


}

 public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
   // no processing inside


}

}
Now inside the Que1 class that implements the Queueable, I have a map that has the record Id as the key..
I am passing the map inside the chained
public class Que1 implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

   public void execute(QueueableContext ctx) {
       // inside the Que2, I am sending an httpRequest per each record Id. But turns out 
       // I am receiving multiple request (1000 or more) for each record Id 
       System.enqueueJob(new Que2(mapVar)); 
   }

}

Inside the que2
public with sharing class Que2 implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts  {
    public void execute(QueueableContext ctx) {

    }

    public static void sendtoAPI(Map<Id, Map<String, String>> input) {
         for(Id idEach : input.keySet()) {
             // send api request
         }

    }
}

What I don't get is I am receiving multiple api request per each record Id when the record Id being passed is unique. Appreciate your help on this. Thanks!

You need to focus on the collection and flow of data, which you have omitted in your question. Please [edit] it to add the specific detail as to how this is done. Including the query and any data transformation you do (such as map creation).
